# Guardar un DateTimePicker en una DB usando tableadapter

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datetimepicker

estoy haciendo un mantenedor en windowsform usando tableadapter en c# y  me gustaria guardar una variable que esta como tipo date en la bd usando el datatimePicker,pero me muestra un error de que no se puede guardar como string y revise la propiedad de la variable en el tableadapter y esta como date al igual que en la base de datos, no se que puede ser ayuda porfavor

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string rut = textRut.Text;
            string nombres = textNombres.Text;
            string paterno = textPaterno.Text;
            string materno = textMaterno.Text;
            DateTime nacimiento = dateTimePicker1;
            DateTime muerte = dateTimePicker2;
            string causa = causaText.Text;
            int cliente = int.Parse(comboCliente.Text);
            int enterrador = int.Parse(comboEnterrador.Text);
            int derecho = int.Parse(comboDerecho.Text);

            difuntoTableAdapter1.AgregarDifunto(rut, nombres, paterno, materno,DateTime nacimiento,muerte,causa,enterrador,cliente,derecho);
            this.difuntoTableAdapter1.FillBy(this.cementerioDataSet1.difunto);
        }
```

intente lo siguente... y tampoco funciona

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTimePicker nacimiento = dateTimePicker1;
            DateTimePicker muerte = dateTimePicker2;
            difuntoTableAdapter1.AgregarDifunto(rut, nombres, paterno, materno, nacimiento,muerte,causa,enterrador,cliente,derecho);
            this.difuntoTableAdapter1.FillBy(this.cementerioDataSet1.difunto);
        }
```

[image: mensaje de error]

Answer (score 0):

Buenas deberás parsear el DateTimePicker a string para despues guardarlo, puedes hacerlo de dos formas:

Desde el TableAdapter:

```
  difuntoTableAdapter1.AgregarDifunto(rut, nombres, paterno, materno, nacimiento.toString(),muerte.toString(),causa,enterrador,cliente,derecho);
```

O bien almacenando el valor del DateTimePicker en un string directamente:

```
  String nacimiento = dateTimePicker1.toString();
  String muerte = dateTimePicker2.toString();
```

Podrás seleccionar el formato de fecha que quieras desde el método toString():

```
String muerte = dateTimePicker2.toString("dd-MM-yyyy"); //ejemplo formato solo dia, mes y año
muerte.toString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"); //ejemplo formato fecha y hora completa
```